# Search dictionary for specific key in tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, search, tuples

I have created a dictionary using tuples

```
stateinfo = {
('Ohio', 'Columbus', 'Scarlet Carnation'): 11747774,
('Texas', 'Austin', 'Bluebonnet'): 30500280,
('North Carolina', 'Raleigh', 'Dogwood'): 10832061,
('Alabama', 'Montgomery', 'Camellia'): 5098746,
('Alaska', 'Juneau', 'Forget-me-not'): 732984,
}
```

I am trying to search the tuples for only the first index (the state) and then print the associated key and value. Below was my latest failure:

```
seek = input("Please enter the State to search: ")
    for key, value in stateinfo.items():
        if seek == key:
            print("yes")
```

literally just testing in the above code

I have searched the net and tried to rework bits and pieces of code to match what I need and keep coming up empty. Can anyone get me on the right path?

Comment: You say dictionary, but `iteritems()` is not a dictionary function.

Comment: yeah I was grasping at straws at that point. I have tried iterating through the table using for key, value in stateinfo.items:  ......changed to put my latest attempt

Comment: `if key[0] == seek:`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to iterate through the keys and check for the values inside the key

```
stateinfo = { 
    ('Ohio', 'Columbus', 'Scarlet Carnation'): 11747774, 
    ('Texas', 'Austin', 'Bluebonnet'): 30500280, 
    ('North Carolina', 'Raleigh', 'Dogwood'): 10832061, 
    ('Alabama', 'Montgomery', 'Camellia'): 5098746, 
    ('Alaska', 'Juneau', 'Forget-me-not'): 732984
}
seek = input("Please the State to search: ") 
for k in stateinfo.keys(): 
    if type(k) in [list, tuple, dict] and seek in k: 
        print(k,stateinfo[k])
```

However, this would check through ALL values inside the key rather than just the state as you mentioned. You don't want to use `seek in k` as this checks whether or not the value `seek` exists anywhere in the iterable `k`. Instead, if you know that it is specifically the first value of the tuple, you can specify it.

```
stateinfo = { 
    ('Ohio', 'Columbus', 'Scarlet Carnation'): 11747774, 
    ('Texas', 'Austin', 'Bluebonnet'): 30500280, 
    ('North Carolina', 'Raleigh', 'Dogwood'): 10832061, 
    ('Alabama', 'Montgomery', 'Camellia'): 5098746, 
    ('Alaska', 'Juneau', 'Forget-me-not'): 732984
}
seek = input("Please the State to search: ") 
for k in stateinfo.keys(): 
    #note: the only difference between the two is changing the line below
    if type(k) in [list, tuple, dict] and seek == k[0]: 
        print(k,stateinfo[k])
```

Comment: That was the magic trick right there. I was so close in one of my earlier attempts but messed up the syntax. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not interested in the dictionary values then there's no point in calling *items()*

If you iterate over a dictionary you'll get its keys (or you can call the *keys()*) function.

Also, you're only interested in the first part of the key (tuple) so you can unpack the key as you iterate over the dictionary.

Which leads to:

```
stateinfo = {
    ('Ohio', 'Columbus', 'Scarlet Carnation'): 11747774,
    ('Texas', 'Austin', 'Bluebonnet'): 30500280,
    ('North Carolina', 'Raleigh', 'Dogwood'): 10832061,
    ('Alabama', 'Montgomery', 'Camellia'): 5098746,
    ('Alaska', 'Juneau', 'Forget-me-not'): 732984,
}

user_input = input('Enter state name: ')

for state, *_ in stateinfo:
    if state == user_input:
        print('Yes')
```